# How to retrieve items based on the total paid amounts

Tags: sql, sql-server-2008

How to add multiple values in SQL Server 2008 r2 and detect items based on paid amounts made.

Order Table:

```
OID           Item         Price
1              A            38
2              B            19
3              C            39.5
```

Payment Table:

```
PID              Amount
1                  38
2                  58.5
```

Now when the query goes like

```
Select ItemName from A inner join B on OID=PID and Price=Amount;
```

Here I'm able to retrieve `ItemA` but this query will not return items B and C because the 
payments made is the sum of the two items.

Comment: You have no data to link these two "facts", you only have payments and items, you don't have an `ItemPayments` table so to speak. What you want to do is impossible unless you have some way of identifying which payments were for which items. Unless of course you want to just return which items could 'fit' into a particular payment - but I'd imagine this isn't the case. Are there no other fields on the `Payment` table? Is there no junction table to join payments to items?

Comment: The point here is "how to retrieve items B and C for the sum of 58.5"

Comment: You can achieve that with the current data but it won't be simple. Is there another relationship that joins payments and items? If not, then when the item and payment tables grow, your query will become more difficult to write, slower to perform and it will likely provide the wrong answers to your questions. Are you sure you aren't doing something wrong? Is this a 'fix' you are trying to apply to data or is this a report? Can you give some background?

Answer (score 1):

Your Table structure is wrong.
you need one extra table with order_Id and Payment_Id.
like OID,PID table name is OrderPayment and then use this Select statement

> Select A.ItemName from OrderPayment inner join A on A.OID = OrderPayment.OID inner join B on B.PID = OrderPayment.PID